# Is WWF project more useful than the typical project in .net?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

Is WWF project more useful than the typical project in .net ? Is WWF used or it's just another experimental feature from microsoft. Kindly elaborate more. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that WF is not an "experimental" feature, at this point.  Microsoft has put a lot of resources into WF.

However, WF is very good for specific types of applications.  I would not say that its "more useful" (or less useful) than other types of applications, as much as it provides some functionality unique in the .NET ecosystem.

If you're developing very long running applications that need to save state, and provide easy customization, for example, than [Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) is an excellent choice.

Comment: I am not able to understand what is meant by "long running applications"... kindly elaborate. thanks...

Comment: @HotTester: Typically examples include things such as an order processing system for an online application.  Somebody places an order, and it may take a day to get approval from one worker, then need to go to the shipping dept. for processing, then take a day (or week) until it ships, then be moved to a pending status, then eventually, at some point get received, etc.  Tracking these types of workflows is where WF excels.

Comment: Hi Reed Copsey i am unsure at what complexity level the wwf are worth the trouble. For example if i have simple workflow open claim, review claim and then approve claim or deny claim or overhaul claim i could write some database logic to persist the state (long running) and some logic to decide which are the available options. 
At what complexity level does wf help me to achieve this in an easier or in a better, more future proof way?
Thanks

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree WF is fairly simple to setup and use for something like that - as soon as you need to persist the items, since they're long running, WF is worth considering.  If you don't need persistence, then TPL Dataflow is likely simpler/nicer.